# Force inline throwing function in destructor

Tags: c++, gcc

If I throw in the destructor of a struct/class and compile with `Werror=terminate`, the compiler will complain with the following error message:

```
warning: 'throw' will always call 'terminate' [-Wterminate]
Compiler: GCC 11.1.0
```

If I however do this the compiler doesn't complain:

```
#include <iostream>

# define FORCE_INLINE __attribute__((always_inline)) inline

FORCE_INLINE void exception_proxy() {
    throw std::invalid_argument("HI");
}

struct T {
    
    T() = default;
    ~T() {
        exception_proxy();
    }
};

int main()
{
}
```

Why is this the case? I am trying to understand exactly why the compiler drops the warning when the function is `inlined`? I understand that the compiler doesn't care to check each function called from a `noexcept` function but this seems a bit counterintuitive given my knowledge?

Godbolt link to show actual inlining: https://godbolt.org/z/eGW7ov9av

Comment: It probably does the check for the warning condition earlier than the inlining.

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you asking why the warning is not produced (which is about the details of how GCC implements this warning) or are you asking how the program will behave?

Comment: `this seems a bit counterintuitive given my knowledge?`  what is counter intuitive? The `the compiler doesn't care to check each function called from a noexcept function` or that the same warnings are emitted for a function independent of `__attribute__((always_inline))` beeing present or not?

Comment: @user17732522 more curious to know why the warning is not produced :)

Comment: @t.niese - what seems odd is that the compiler doesn't warn that the function is throwing an exception (without the facade of a function call)

Comment: the compiler does not "ignore the throw". If you actually execute the code then you'll see that the exception is thrown and that the program does terminate https://godbolt.org/z/T7WYGx13d.  The reason for the warning is still there, the compiler just fails to issue the warning. Note that warnings are important for compilers, but still much lower in priority than generating the correct expected output.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number not saying exception wont be thrown - curious to know exactly why the warning disappears with this construction.

Comment: you might want to rephrase the question a little. "I am trying to understand exactly why the compiler ignores the throw when the function is inlined?" is not what you actually mean if I understand your comment correctly

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number edited, thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

> If I throw in the destructor of a struct/class and compile with Werror=terminate, the compiler will complain with the following error message:
>
> Why is this the case?

You get a warning because you throw in a noexcept function.

> If I however do this the compiler doesn't complain:
>
> Why is this the case?

You don't get a warning because you don't throw in a noexcept function. You throw in a potentially throwing function.

---

> I am trying to understand exactly why the compiler drops the warning when the function is inlined?

The inlining attribute has no effect on the warning one way or another. You may find that you won't get a warning even if you remove the inlining attribute.